# Missing row when data value is 0 in teradata

Tags: sql, group-by, count, teradata

I am trying to do a group-by in a query but every time the data has a 0, the group by does not show the entire row. How do I fix this?

This is the regular query

```
select 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sr.sr_number) AS NEW_CASES
FROM table sr
where 
    sr.business_unit in('BU1')
    and OPENED_DATE < trunc(current_Date)
    and OPENED_DATE > trunc(current_date -2)
    and sr.status = 'Open'
```

The output is

```
NEW_CASES
0
```

But when I do a group by. The entire row is gone.

```
select 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sr.sr_number) AS NEW_CASES,
    sr.business_unit
FROM table sr
where 
    sr.business_unit in('BU1','BU2','BU3' )
    and OPENED_DATE < trunc(current_Date)
    and OPENED_DATE > trunc(current_date -2)
    and sr.status = 'Open'
group by sr.business_unit
```

The group by output is

```
New_CASES    BUSINESS_UNIT
      200    BU2
      300    BU3
```

Desired output:

```
New_CASES    BUSINESS_UNIT
        0    BU1
      200    BU2
      300    BU3
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Teradata?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: The DB is teradata but going through Oracle SQL developer

Answer (score 1):

One option is to start from a fixed list of values, and then bring the table with a `left join`, like so:

```
select b.business_unit, count(distinct t.sr_number) as new_cases
from (
    select 'bu1' business_unit from dual
    union all select 'bu2' from dual
    union all select 'bu3' from dual
) b
left join mytable t
    on  t.business_unit = b.business_unit
    and t.opened_date > trunc(current_date -2)
    and t.opened_date < trunc(current_date)
    and t.status = 'open'
group by b.business_unit
```

In Teradata, the syntax is somehow cumbersome:

```
select b.business_unit, count(distinct t.sr_number) as new_cases
from (
    select * from (select 'bu1' as business_unit) x
    union all select * from (select 'bu2' as business_unit ) x
    union all select * from (select 'bu3' as business_unit ) x
) b
left join mytable t
    on  t.business_unit = b.business_unit
    and t.opened_date > trunc(current_date -2)
    and t.opened_date < trunc(current_date)
    and t.status = 'open'
group by b.business_unit
```

Comment: [teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.13] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or '(' between the 'from' keyword and the 'dual' keyword.

Comment: @RLearner: this was Oracle syntax. Does if work of you remove all occurences of `from dual`?

Comment: let me try by replacing it with the actual table. I think dual is a default table in oracle db  right?

Comment: OK So that did not work. I did get the BU1 to show up as 0 with two other BUs but the data was wrong for the other 2 and one the other BUs with a larger name was cutoff (missing characters in the name)

Comment: @RLearner: I did a little research and updated my answer with a query that should work in Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join`.  In Oracle, this would look like

```
select b.business_unit, COUNT(DISTINCT sr.sr_number) AS NEW_CASES
from (select 'BU1' as business_unit from dual union all
      select 'BU2' as business_unit from dual union all
      select 'BU3' as business_unit from dual 
     ) b left join
     sr
     on sr.business_unit = b.business_unit and
        sr.OPENED_DATE < trunc(current_Date) and
        sr.OPENED_DATE > trunc(current_date -2) and
        sr.status = 'Open'
group by b.business_unit
```

EDIT:

Teradata doesn't have a really convenient way to create a derived table of constant values, but you can do it:

```
select b.business_unit, COUNT(DISTINCT sr.sr_number) AS NEW_CASES
from (select 'BU1' as business_unit from (select 1 as dummy) t union all
      select 'BU2' as business_unit from (select 1 as dummy) t  union all
      select 'BU3' as business_unit from (select 1 as dummy) t  
     ) b left join
     sr
     on sr.business_unit = b.business_unit and
        sr.OPENED_DATE < trunc(current_Date) and
        sr.OPENED_DATE > trunc(current_date -2) and
        sr.status = 'Open'
group by b.business_unit
```

Comment: Got this error when I tried that:    [teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.13] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or '(' between the 'from' keyword and the 'dual' keyword.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried your teradata solution, but it does not seem to be working.I get only 3 rows (expected 4). But the three that do I get it does not show complete data.While the business unit that was supposed to show 0 is now showing zero. There rest are now a mess. the business names are cutoff and their corresponding values are wrong. (when I run them with out the group by it is correct)

Comment: You should be expecting three rows, just like your question asks for.

Comment: In Teradata, the first subquery in the UNION [ALL] determines the data types of the result, plus in Teradata transaction mode string truncation happens silently. If you include constant or unlike values it is recommended to explicitly CAST them to the appropriate result type (and length). If you use ANSI transaction mode, then string truncation will be flagged as an error - though character literals become case sensitive by default.